# Append Pandas Series to DataFrame as a column

Tags: pandas, series

I have panadas dataframe (df) like ['key','col1','col2','col3'] and I have pandas series (sr) for which the index is the same as 'key' in data frame. I want to append the series to the dataframe at the new column called col4 with the same 'key'. I have the following code:

```
for index, row in segmention.iterrows():    
     df[df['key']==row['key']]['col4']=sr.loc[row['key']]
```

The code is very slow. I assume there should be more efficient and better way to do that. could you please help?

Comment: IIUC then `df['col4'] = df['key'].map(sr)` should work

Comment: It would be useful for you to post a representative example and desired output to avoid ambiguity

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) as mentioned `EdChum`:

```
df['col4'] = df['key'].map(sr)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3 key  col4
0     4     7     1   A     2
1     5     8     3   B     4
2     6     9     5   C     1
```

Or assign with [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index('key')
df['col4'] = sr
print (df)
     col1  col2  col3  col4
key                        
A       4     7     1     2
B       5     8     3     4
C       6     9     5     1
```

If dont need `align` data in `Series` by `key` use (see difference `2,1,4` vs `4,1,2`):

```
df['col4'] = sr.values
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3 key  col4
0     4     7     1   A     4
1     5     8     3   B     1
2     6     9     5   C     2
```

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'key':[1,2,3],
                   'col1':[4,5,6],
                   'col2':[7,8,9],
                   'col3':[1,3,5]}, index=list('ABC'))

print (df)
   col1  col2  col3  key
A     4     7     1    1
B     5     8     3    2
C     6     9     5    3

sr = pd.Series([4,1,2], index=list('BCA'))
print (sr)
B    4
C    1
A    2
dtype: int64

df['col4'] = df['key'].map(sr)
print (df)
   col1  col2  col3 key  col4
0     4     7     1   A     2
1     5     8     3   B     4
2     6     9     5   C     1
```

---

```
df = df.set_index('key')
df['col4'] = sr
print (df)
     col1  col2  col3  col4
key                        
A       4     7     1     2
B       5     8     3     4
C       6     9     5     1
```

Comment: I think the OP want's to add a new column 'col4' like a `map` or `merge` based on `key`

Answer (score 18):

You can simply do:

```
df['col4'] = sr
```

If don't misunderstand.

Comment: This only works if the Series doesn't have a name, or if the index of the DataFrame and the Series is the same.

Answer (score 2):

This is really a good use case for `join`, where the left dataframe aligns a column with the index of the right dataframe/series. You have to make sure your Series has a name for it to work

```
sr.name = 'some name'
df.join(sr, on='key')
```